# Execute the SQL command below. List all records in the tb_Pets table where pet the pet name’s second character is the Letter A, U, or I

Tags: sql

The record is "no data found" what is wrong with my code?

```
SELECT * FROM TB_PETS
WHERE PETNAME LIKE '_[aui]%';
```

Comment: `LIKE` doesn't recognise regular expression patterns.

Comment: Oracle doesn't support regex in `like`. Use different conditions with `OR` or [`regexp_like` condition](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Pattern-matching-Conditions.html#GUID-D2124F3A-C6E4-4CCA-A40E-2FFCABFD8E19).

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Oracle?

Answer (score 1):

A simple option is

```
where lower(substr(petname, 2, 1)) in ('a', 'u', 'i')
```

i.e. you don't need regular expressions.

---

If you want it, try

```
where regexp_like(petname, '_a|u|i', 'i')
```

i.e. name can start with anything (exactly one character, followed by a, u or i (case insensitive).

---

```
SQL> select * from tb_pets;

PETNAME
-------
Mickey
Paul
Axel
xyz

SQL> select *
  2  from tb_pets
  3  where lower(substr(petname, 2, 1)) in ('a', 'u', 'i');

PETNAME
-------
Mickey
Paul

SQL> select *
  2  from tb_pets
  3  where regexp_like(petname, '_a|u|i', 'i');

PETNAME
-------
Mickey
Paul

SQL>
```

Comment: I'd rather go for (petname like '_a%' or petname like '_u%' or petname like '_i%'), although it is a rather long logical expression. regexp_like is not as good for performance as the simple like. Not sure which would perform better for large volumes of data, like millions of rows.